# Linux terminal tool dosent run one of the getopt commands

Tags: c, linux, terminal

So I have a simple terminal tool here that makes use of getopt but when I run it everything runs smoothly except "cast -s" it returns "cast: invalid option -- 's'" but it fails silently without any error messages. Ive tried it on different hardware, operating systems and more but it dosent seem to work just right

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#define DATA_SIZE 1000

void print_help(void)
{
    printf("Help\n");
    printf("> cast -d (deletes file)\n");
    printf("> cast -r (renames file)\n");
    printf("> cast -c (create new file)\n");
    printf("> cast -s (scans for file in directory)\n");
    printf("________________________________________\n");
    printf("Find an error or a bug? please submit it in the issues section on github\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int option_val = 0;
    int opt_delete = 0;
    int opt_help = 0;
    int opt_rename = 0;
    int opt_create = 0;
    int opt_scan = 0;

    while ((option_val = getopt(argc, argv, "dhrc")) != -1) {
        switch (option_val) {
        case 'd':
        char filename[65]; //Hope your filename isnt bigger than this

    printf("Filename or path to file: ");
    scanf("%s", filename); // checks to see if your filename isnt bigger than specified

    if (remove(filename) != 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Errno: %d\n", errno);
      perror("Error msg");
    } else printf("%s, deleted.\n", filename);

            opt_delete = 1;
            break;
    case 's':
        {
            DIR *dp;
            struct dirent *dirp;

            if (argc != 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "usage: s directory_name\n");
                return 1;
            }

            if ((dp = opendir(argv[1])) == NULL) {
            perror("cant copen");
            return 2;
            }
            while((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
                printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);

            closedir(dp);
            return 0;
        }

    opt_scan = 1;
    break;

        case 'r':
            char file[65], new[65];

            printf("File: ");
            scanf("%s", file);

            printf("New name: ");
            scanf("%s", new);

           if (rename(file, new) != 0)
           {
              fprintf(stderr, "Errno: %d\n", errno);
              perror("Error msg");
           } else printf("%s --> %s", file, new);
            opt_rename = 1;
            break;
        case 'c':
        FILE *f = fopen("Castdocument.txt", "w+");
        
        fprintf(f, "Finished with maybe no errors? Rename this file to whatever you would like and change the filename extension with ""cast -r""");
            
        printf("File created! (Check your home directory for ""Castdocument.txt"" file and modify that to fit your needs)");

        fclose(f);    

        opt_create = 1;
            break;

        case 'h':
            opt_help = 1;
            break;
        default: /* '?' */
            //print_help();
        }
    }

    if (opt_delete) {
        printf("\n");
    } if (opt_rename) {
        printf("\n");
    } if (opt_help) {
        print_help();
    } if (opt_create) {
        printf("\n");
    } 
}
```

Ive attempted to run this on a different system to no avail

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your `getopt(argc, argv, "dhrc")` call does not list `s` among the options to be recognized.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You say that it reports "invalid option" but then say it fails silently with no error message. Which is it?